# Use light box in dynamic php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi i created a php page that read images dynamically from a folder and put them in some page for gallery.
but i cant use linked css file and i have to use all of my css in to  but thats not the real problem, the problem is i cant use jQuery neither in  nor from separate script.js file.
the second problem is i want to use lightbox for viewing images but thats not work. here is php code:

```
$folder = 'images/shirini/';
$filetype = '*.jpg';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);

$sortedArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$sortedArray[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($files[$i]))] = $files[$i];
}
$i =1;
$n = 1;

krsort($sortedArray);
echo '<div class=\"total\">';
foreach ($sortedArray as &$filename) {

echo '<a href="#img'.$n.'"><img src="'.$filename.'" /></a>';
echo '<a href="#" class=\"lightbox\" id=\"#img'.$n.'\"><img src="'.$filename.'"/ </a>';

$i += 1;

$n += 1;

while($i === 7) {
        echo '<br>';
    $i=1;
}
};

echo '</div>';
```

here is CSS code:
    body {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #acacac;
    text-align: center;
    }

```
img{
position:relative;
width:150px;

right:0px;
top:0px;
border:0.3spx solid red;
/* Apply a CSS3 Transition to width, height, top and left properties */
transition: width 0.3ss ease,height 0.3ss ease,left 0.3ss ease,top 0.3ss ease;
-webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
vertical-align: middle;
}

img:hover{
width:300px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:9999;
}

.frame{
display: table-row;
}

.total{
overflow:visible;
display: block;

}

.total ul{
clear:both;
}

.total li
{
width:102px;
height:82px;
margin:4px;
float: left;
overflow:visible;
display: block;
}

.lightbox {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: black;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
max-width: 90%;
max-height: 80%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox:target {
display: block;
outline: none;
}
```

anyone know how to use lightbox or jquery or link CSS's out of html??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understanding you correctly...

Why don't you create separate files and just include the php script? So I would probably do something like this in your case (if you want to keep the php you posted separate too)

Create
- gallery.php
- style.css
- gallery-images.php

Your gallery-images.php would have the php code you pasted above in.

style.css would have the css you posted in

Your gallery.php would look something like:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>My gallery</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php include('gallery-images.php'); ?>  

  <script src="/path/to/jquery.js">
  <script src="/path/to/lightbox.js">
  </body>
 </html>
```

This way you would be able to use any css/scripts you wanted within gallery.php

Does that help?